# Linear regression with sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm performing a linear regression that will predict the price of rooms, in my Airbnb dataset.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


X = df2[['room_type', 'neighbourhood']] #These are categorical values

X = pd.get_dummies(data=X, drop_first=True)

y = df2['price']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=100)

model = LinearRegression()

model.fit(X_train,y_train)

coeff_parameter = pd.DataFrame(model.coef_,X.columns,columns=['Coefficient'])

print(coeff_parameter)

predictions = model.predict(X_test)

print("Here are the predictions:",predictions)

sns.regplot(y=y_test,x=predictions)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chv7E.png)

As I look at the plot, I see that too many points are away from my predictive line.

Could you help me with my Python code ?

Comment: Did  you perform outlier analysis ?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. Actually, when plotting those information, it appears that a lot of outliers pop up

Comment: Don't you think that model is underfitting a bit? Have you tried other regression models?

Comment: Multiple prices for the same independent variable suggest to me that your choice of function is too simple.  You are badly underfitting.  You need to add more features to your model to make it useful.

Answer (score 0):

The fit of the line is correct mathematically. Linear regression is a "best fit" model and therefore will be drawn to the mean of your values.

I'm not sure what help you need. You should run model metrics like R2 and Mean Squared Error (MSE & RMSE).

Just because visually the model is a bit weak, it could perform well enough based on fit statistics.

Something that might help the optics of your model could be to remove outliers. To do this you can limit the data to 95 percentile.
You may also want to use data normalization.